# Spectral Radius of element wise absolute function of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix $A$ with diagonal elements that are all $0$. Is it necessarily true that $\rho(|A|) \geq \rho(A)$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius function? Using Gershgorin Circle Theorem, one can only conclude that both $\rho(A)$ and $\rho(|A|)$ lie in the interval $(-\max_i \sum_{j \neq i}a_{ij}, \max_i \sum_{j \neq i}a_{ij})$, but that's where I am stuck. Can anyone help me? Specifically, I am interested to know if there's any truth to the following suppositions:

1. $\rho(|A|) < 1 \implies \rho(A) < 1$
2. $\rho(A) < 1 \iff \rho(|A|) < 1$

Comment: You need to clarify the meaning of the symbol $|A|$. The answer below by Fred interprets $|A|$ as $(A^\ast A)^{1/2}$, but this symbol is also used (often in the literature of nonnegative matrices) to denote the *entrywise* absolute value of $A$.

Comment: You're right. I should have been more specific in the body of my question. I was indeed referring to the absolute value of $A$, as I mention in the title of my question.

Comment: $(A^\ast A)^{1/2}$ is also called "absolute value" because it is the positive semidefinite component $P$ in the polar decomposition $A=UP$. If you mean entrywise absolute value, you should insert "entrywise" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If we equip the space $ \mathbb C^n$ with the euclidian norm $|| \cdot ||_2 $ and define for a matrix $T \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ the operator norm by

$$ ||T||= \max\{ ||Tx||_2: ||x||_2=1\},$$

then we have for a symmetric matrix $A$, that

$$\rho(A)=||A||.$$

Now let $A$ be a symmetric matrix. $|A|$ is defined by $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}.$ Hence $|A|$ is symmetric.

We get:

$$\rho(|A|)^2=\rho(|A|^2)=\rho(A^*A)=||A^*A||=||A||^2,$$

thus

$$\rho(|A|)=||A||= \rho(A).$$

Remark: this result holds, more general,  for symmetic operators on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thank you Fred. By $|A|$, I meant the element-wise absolute value of the matrix $A$. My apologies for the confusion.